# Include HTML file into Smarty .tpl file

Tags: html, include, smarty

```
{if $loggedin}

{literal}
{include file="allhead.html"}
{/literal}

{else}

{literal}
{include file="allhead1.html"}
{/literal}

{/if}
```

How do I include the code contained into an HTML file in a smarty .tpl file? I've tried different solutions on various forums, but none work.

---

You mean I have to create a PHP file with this:

```
<?php
$smarty->assign('allhead', '/public_html/billing/templates/allhead.html');
$smarty->assign('allhead1', '/public_html/billing/templates/allhead1.html');
?>
```

Then add into the Smarty .tpl file this:

```
{if $loggedin}

{include file="$allhead"}

{else}

{include file="$allhead1"}

{/if}
```

But how will the smarty template know it got to check the $ vars from the PHP file?

Comment: your include calls shouldn't be wrapped in literal tags...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP:

```
$smarty->assign('allhead1', 'FULL_PATH_T0_FILE');
```

In Smarty Template:

```
<body>
<!-- don't put literal tags around include -->
{include file="$allhead1"}  
</body>
```